# Orientation of Polarized Capacitor in a High Pass Filter

Tags: capacitor, amplifier

Recently I have decided to learn Arduino and circuits during my summer break. I have been doing different projects with a book I bought. One of the projects inside has a High Pass Filter. I understand the function of it but I am very confused as to the polarity of the capacitor. I am confused as to why the negative side is facing Vin when usually, for example LEDs and other diodes, the positive terminal would be facing the input. Granted, the input voltage in this case is supplied by a pin set to output as pulse width modulation with square waves. Essentially, why is the polarity going from left to right (negative to positive) when the voltage going in would, from my understanding create a drop of from left to right(positive to negative)? Thank you.

[image: The High Pass Filter I am to be constructing with the Polarized Capacitor having the negative terminal face the input voltage]

[image: Negative Side of the Capacitor facing the input voltage]

Comment: Looks like a mistake to me.

Comment: -ve side always points towards 0V on single +ve Vcc

Answer (score 2):

### Short answer

There's a mistake.

### Details

Normally, you want an electrolytic capacitor's positive terminal to be connected to a node having greater voltage.

In the given schematic, most likely the highpass filter formed by 1000μF-1kΩ pair is there to remove just the DC offset along with very low frequencies because its cutoff frequency is around 1.6 Hz. So, since the input signal is a 5V PWM with variable duty-cycle, the expected output is an AC signal with positive (+2.5V) and negative (-2.5V) peaks: The input has a 5V peak, and the output will have a 2.5V peak (max.)<sup>**1**</sup>. So the positive terminal of C1 should be connected to Arduino's output.

<sup>**1**</sup> There's the transistor with its emitter connected to the speaker, so the output will not have equal-amplitude peaks actually. This will not change the conclusion, though. You can simulate the circuit. By the way, I have no idea why the load is connected to the transistor as shown.

Comment: It's connected to the emitter like that to save a freewheel diode, probably. I think there should be a base resistor though.